# Saving realtime data in an array to viewed later (Android application)

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to save data from an EEG headset (int value) that is generated every second.

I am trying to save the different value, produced each second, in the array so that the values of the array can then be viewed in the next activity.

My current code runs ok, but in the net activity it only gives

```
[l@42d01e90
```

What is my error?

Code where attempting to save the data:

note: the switch statment is only concerned with what data type to deal with.

The data I wish to save is `msg.arg1`

```
case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:

                //save level from each second in an array?
                        for(int i=0; i<medResults.length; i++){

                            msg.arg1= medResults[i];
                        }
```

Array im trying to save the values to:

```
int[] medResults= new int[100];
```

The intents that are passing the data are working but the data itself isnt getting shown properly.

The activity recieving the data:

```
public class MeditationResults extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.meditationresults);

        // List view to hold the test results
        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults);

        // getting data from the previous activity via intents
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");

        tv.setText(results.toString());

    }

}
```

The full activity that contains the switch statement (for reference):

```
/**
* Class holding the activity that has the 10 random sums for the user to answer
* @author Ross
* 
*/
public class Meditation extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    // declare vars
    TextView text;
    EditText answer;
    Button submit;
    TextView meditation;
    int random1;
    int random2;
    String[] question = new String[10];
    int correctAnswer[] = new int[10];
    int[] results = new int[10];
    int[] medResults= new int[100];
    int score = 0;
    int questionNumber = 1;
    MediaPlayer correctNoise;
    MediaPlayer incorrectNoise;
    //Below are all imports from neurosky, bluetooth etc
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter; 
    TGDevice device;
    TGEegPower eegPower;

    final boolean rawEnabled = true; // ??


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.meditation);

        // initialising variables
        initialiseVars();

        // set up random
        setUpRandom();

        // Set text view equal to question in array
        text.setText(question[questionNumber - 1]);

        // set on click listener for the submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);

        // updateQuestion
        updateQuestion();


        //CODE RELATING TO NEUROSKY
        // Check if Blue tooth is available on the Android device
                bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {

                    // Alert user that Bluetooth is not available
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    // finish();
                    return;

                } else {

                    // create the TGDevice
                    // Android app is connecting to hardware device using the standard
                    // constructor
                    device = new TGDevice(bluetoothAdapter, handler);
                }

                //meditation.append("NeuroSky: " + TGDevice.version + " " + TGDevice.build_title);
                //meditation.append("\n");


                //Code to connect device...
                if (device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING
                        && device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                    // Connect the device to the Neurosky Headset (starting connection
                    // process)
                    device.connect(rawEnabled); // note: rawEnabled allows raw sample
                                                // data to be sent to device

                    device.EKGstartDetection();

                }



    }

    /**
     * Method that initialises variables
     */
    public void initialiseVars() {

        correctNoise = MediaPlayer.create(Meditation.this, R.raw.correctnoise);
        incorrectNoise = MediaPlayer.create(Meditation.this, R.raw.incorrectnoise);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTopRandomTest);
        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterAnswerRandomTest);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitRandomTest);
        meditation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSeeMeditation);

    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the random sum for user to answer
     */
    public void setUpRandom() {

        // setting up new random
        Random random = new Random();

        // Generating random number between 1 and 12
        random1 = random.nextInt(12) + 1;
        // Generating another random number between 1 and 12
        random2 = random.nextInt(12) + 1;
        // Creating random question String
        question[questionNumber - 1] = random1 + " x " + random2 + " = ";
        // Creating correct answer to question
        correctAnswer[questionNumber - 1] = random1 * random2; 

    }

    /**
     * Method that updates question after each click
     */
    public void updateQuestion() {

        // updating question after each click
        setUpRandom();
        text.setText(question[questionNumber - 1]);
        answer.setText("");

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // sets text view equal to what is entered in editText
        final String entry = answer.getText().toString();
        // convert from string value to int
        int a = Integer.parseInt(entry); //

        // setting the user answer equal to the correct part of results array
        results[questionNumber - 1] = a;

        // If user answer is equal to correct answer then increase score
        if (a == correctAnswer[questionNumber - 1]) {
            score++;
            correctNoise.start();

        }else{

            incorrectNoise.start();


        }

        // if question number is under 10
        if (questionNumber < 10) {
            // updates question number
            questionNumber++;
            // called after an answer is given
            updateQuestion();

        } else {

            //CHANGE THIS IF IT DOESNT WORK

//          // Passing values to the results activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MeditationResults.class);
            intent.putExtra("results", medResults);
//          intent.putExtra("Questions", question);
//          intent.putExtra("CorrectAnswer", correctAnswer);
//          intent.putExtra("score", score);
            // Start Activity
            this.startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

    //METHODS ETC RELATING TO NEUROSKY

    /**
     * Handles messages from TGDevice
     * 
     */
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_EEG_POWER:

                //WILL NEED TO CHANGE TO PUTPUT TO SCREEN. 
//              Log.d("LSD", "highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
//              Log.d("LSD", "highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
//              Log.d("LSD", "midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
//              Log.d("LSD", "delta: " + eegPower.delta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "theta: " + eegPower.theta);

                break;
            case TGDevice.MSG_STATE_CHANGE:

                // actual value of the message is determined by msg.arg1
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case TGDevice.STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    meditation.append("Connecting...\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    meditation.append("Connected.\n");
                    device.start();
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_NOT_FOUND:
                    meditation.append("Could not connect any of the paired BT devices.  Turn them on and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_NO_DEVICE:
                    meditation.append("No Bluetooth devices paired.  Pair your device and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_BT_OFF:
                    meditation.append("Bluetooth is off.  Turn on Bluetooth and try again.");
                    break;

                case TGDevice.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    meditation.append("Disconnected.\n");
                } /* end switch on msg.arg1 */

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_POOR_SIGNAL:
                //meditation.append("PoorSignal: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_HEART_RATE:
                meditation.append("Heart rate: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:
                /* Handle raw EEG/EKG data here */
                //tv.append("RAW EEG: " + msg.arg1); Note: commented out as trying to get the exact figs (gamma etc)
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_ATTENTION:
                //meditation.append("Attention: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:

                //save level from each second in an array?
                        for(int i=0; i<medResults.length; i++){

                            msg.arg1= medResults[i];
                        }

                //display each level on screen as it changes each second
                meditation.setText("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                if(msg.arg1<=35){

                    //if mediation level is low it turns red
                    meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                }else if((msg.arg1<=70)&&(msg.arg1>=35)){
                      meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }else{

                        meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                /


                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_BLINK:
                meditation.append("Blink: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            default:
                break;

            } /* end switch on msg.what */

            //sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); May need to use this again if the scroll view is needed!

        } /* end handleMessage() */

    }; /* end Handler */

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks on the "Connect" button.
     * 
     * @param view
     */
    public void doStuff(View view) {
        // if the device is not currently connecting and is not already
        // connected
        if (device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING
                && device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            // Connect the device to the Neurosky Headset (starting connection
            // process)
            device.connect(rawEnabled); // note: rawEnabled allows raw sample
                                        // data to be sent to device

            device.EKGstartDetection();

        }

    } /* end doStuff() */

    /**
     * Method that closes app if the back 
     * button is pressed
     */
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                device.close();
                this.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake you seem to have made is the way you display the result.

`tv.setText(results.toString());`

By default, the toString() method returns a string describing the object, as explained in the official documentation:

```
Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.
```

This is why you get `[l@42d01e90`. In order to display the values of your array, just use a loop to display each value one by one:

```
for(int i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
     //Displays the data in LogCat
     Log.e("LOG", results[i]);
}
```

But displaying some many values to your user is not a good idea I think. You should instead calculate an average and display it in a TextView.

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
         sum += results[i];
    }

int average = sum/results.length;
tv.setText(average);
```

Hope it helps!